# How to use raw socket send and receive arp package in python

Tags: python, sockets, arp, recvfrom

I need to "send and receive `ARP` packet in one program". I'm aware that the `scapy` packet is already do it quiet well, and you just need to pass some argument. However, I want to know much further than just pass argument. So, if you recommend `scapy` as answer, it might not help.

#### Code

````
python
import struct
import socket
import binascii

rawSocket = socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW,
                          socket.htons(0x0003))
rawSocket.bind(("wlp5s0", socket.htons(0x0003)))

source_mac = binascii.unhexlify('00:A0:C9:14:C8:29'.replace(':', ''))
#b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' sender mac address
dest_mac = binascii.unhexlify('ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'.replace(':', ''))
#  b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'  target mac address

source_ip = "192.168.100.3"  # sender ip address
dest_ip = "192.168.100.1"  # target ip address

# Ethernet Header
protocol = 0x0806  # 0x0806 for ARP
eth_hdr = struct.pack("!6s6sH", dest_mac, source_mac, protocol)

# ARP header
htype = 1  # Hardware_type ethernet
ptype = 0x0800  # Protocol type TCP
hlen = 6  # Hardware address Len
plen = 4  # Protocol addr. len
operation = 1  # 1=request/2=reply
src_ip = socket.inet_aton(source_ip)
dst_ip = socket.inet_aton(dest_ip)
arp_hdr = struct.pack("!HHBBH6s4s6s4s", htype, ptype, hlen, plen, operation,
                      source_mac, src_ip, dest_mac, dst_ip)

packet = eth_hdr + arp_hdr
rawSocket.send(packet)
rawSocket.recvfrom(65535)
```
By the way I can clear see the packet already send and reply but `Wireshark`
````

[image: Screenshot]

#### Platform:

> OS: Linux Ubuntn 16.04
>
> Interpreter: Python 3.5.2

Comment: Hmmmm, what’s your question ? ^^

Comment: My code could not suit my need to receive the ARP replay packet. Do you know why?

Comment: What’s against Scapy ? You could do it in one line. Or perhaps you’re doing this for an educational purpose ?

Comment: Indeed, personally I want to know how to use raw socket to complete it too.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the bind you should set it to 0 for the second parameter:
rawSocket.bind(("wlp5s0", 0))

I was able to receive ARP packets no problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).